# while loop in c language

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

I am new in programming and i am currently using visual studio 2013 for c programming, question is when i ran the code, it asks me which i want to choose so i choose number 1, then it asks me 'Anna korkeus'( means give me height) then i  write 1 , it keeps giving me something for eternity, but what i want is, when i write 1 it must print this = '        printf("Pienin mitta on 5 cm ja suurin 50cm, anna uudelleen \n");
' and after that because the number which i gave was wrong it must ask me again the same question 'Anna korkeus' untill i give the right number between 5 > h || h >  50

Thank you in advance, sorry english is not my native language

```
#include < stdio.h>
#define   PII   3.14
void main(void)
{
    char rivi[128]; /* sy”tetty rivi luetaan t„h„n */
    /* mahdollinen ylim„„r„inen sy”te */
    float pii;
    float h;
    float r;
    float v;
    float kartio;
    float luku;
    int  number;

    system("cls");

    printf("1 ympyr„lieri” \n");
    printf("2 ympyr„kartio \n");
    printf("Lasketaan tilavuutta, valitse tuotteista: \n");


    scanf_s("%d", &number);
    if ( number == 1){
        printf("Valitsit ympyr„lieri”n \n");

    luku=printf("Anna korkeus: \n");
    scanf_s("%f", &h);

    while (5 > h || h >  50){
        printf("Pienin mitta on 5 cm ja suurin 50cm, anna uudelleen \n");
        printf("Anna korkeus: \n");
    }


    printf("Anna sade: \n");
    scanf_s("%f", &r);
    if (5 > r || r >  50){
        printf("Pienin mitta on 5 cm ja suurin 50cm, anna uudelleen \n");
    }

    v = PII*r*r*h;
    printf("Ympyralierion tilavuus on: %f\n", v);
}
        else if (number == 2){

            printf("Valitsit ympyr„kartion \n");

    printf("Anna korkeus: ");
    scanf_s("%f", &h);
    if (5 > h || h >  50){
        printf("Pienin mitta on 5 cm ja suurin 50cm, anna uudelleen \n");
    }
    printf("Anna sade: ");
    scanf_s("%f", &r);
    if (5 > r || r >  50){
        printf("Pienin mitta on 5 cm ja suurin 50cm, anna uudelleen \n");
    }
    v = (PII*r*r*h)/3;
    printf("Ympyrakartion tilavuus on: %f\n", v);

    }
}
```

Comment: You have a while loop that loops while the value of h is not between 5 and 50, but which never changes the value of h in the loop so it can never end.

Comment: i would be happy if you could correct the code : )

Comment: Like @PaulTomblin already wrote: put your printf/scanf inside the loop and checking for "h < 5 || h > 50" might be an easier read ... As it would be translating your Finnish to English too ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code that way:

```
do {
  printf("Anna korkeus: \n");
  scanf_s("%f", &h);

  if (h < 5 || h >  50) {
    printf("Pienin mitta on 5 cm ja suurin 50cm, anna uudelleen \n");
  }
}
while(h < 5 || h >  50);
```

In the next step you might consider moving the redundant check of h to a function which returns true or false depending on the input.

Comment: it wont work just keeps giving error, 'error c2059: syntax error : 'else',' IntelliSense expected 'while',IntelliSense expected a '('

Comment: could you just correct the whole code and send me, then i can learn from it

Comment: I suggest taking the return value from the input like `int res = scanf_s("%f", &h);` and testing `res` along with the supposed input value.